# How can I display manu item based on logical opertor in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I display "Logout", "Add Product" and "Manage Inventory"(protected route) menu in navbar if user are log-in. If user are not login then only unprotected route will show for ex. Home and blog.

If I add logout button inside logical operator then it's working fine but then I add two more route "Add Product" and "Manage Inventory" then "Add Product" and "Manage Inventory" display after logout.

I tired several ways but failed to figure out. Please guide me to fix this issue.

Please find my code below:

```js
import { onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "../../fireBase.init";

const NavBar = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                setUser(user)
            }
            else {
                setUser({});
            }
        });
    }, []);

    const handleLogout = () => {
        signOut(auth).then(() => {

        }).catch((error) => {
            <p>Error: {error.message}</p>
        });

    }


    return (
        <Navbar bg="success" expand="lg" sticky="top">
            <Container fluid>
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">RIM COMPUTERS</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll"></Navbar.Toggle>
                <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
                    <Nav className="ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0" navbarScroll >
                        <Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/blog">Blog</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/addproduct">Add Product</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/manage-inventory">Manage Inventory</Nav.Link>
                        {
                            user?.uid
                                ?

                                <button onClick={handleLogout} className='btn btn-warning'>Logout</button>
                                :
                                <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/login"><button className='btn btn-warning'>Login</button></Nav.Link>
                        }

                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator for add product and manage inventory.

{(user?.email)?<Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/addproduct">Add Product</Nav.Link>: ""
}

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am still confused about how can I add multiple menu to show for login user

i did modify code according to your instruction: 

here it is:

{(user?.uid) ? <Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/addproduct">Add Product</Nav.Link> : <Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/manage-inventory">Manage Inventory</Nav.Link> : <button onClick={handleLogout} className='btn btn-warning'>Logout</button>
                                :
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/login"><button className='btn btn-warning'>Login</button></Nav.Link>}

Comment: you can't add multiple in that way!!!

there is two condition one true and one false. Here is the fix maybe work
 {
(user?.uid) ? 
(<Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/addproduct">Add Product</Nav.Link> <Nav.Link className="px-2 text-light" as={Link} to="/manage-inventory">Manage Inventory</Nav.Link> <button onClick={handleLogout} className='btn btn-warning'>Logout</button> <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/login"><button className='btn btn-warning'>Login</button></Nav.Link>)
:
 ""

}

Comment: thanks for your reply, I did fix the issue by using 3 ternary operator. I know this isn't the best way but for the time being, it will be okay for me. Many thanks for your cooperation.